# How to get specific value from JSON and display it's elements on CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible to get specific elements from JSON and display it's other elements on collectionView?

**Broader question:**
This is my JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "floor": 1,
    "full_name": "Ernst & Young Audit LLC",
    "description": "Ernst & Young («Эрнст энд Янг», в наст. время — EY) — британская аудиторско-консалтинговая компания, одна из крупнейших в мире. Основана в 1989 путём слияния американских аудиторских компаний A. C. Young, основанной Артуром Янгом в 1906 году, и Ernst & Whinney, основанной Элвином Эрнстом в 1903 году.\r\n\r\nПодробнее: http://www.ey.com/",
    "logo_url": "http://########/EY_logo13.png"
}
```

Here, I want to get `full_name`, `description` and `logo_url` referring to `floor` which is an Integer that has values of 2,3,4,5.

For example:

if the `floor` is 1, I want to get values from the floor 1, if it is 2 then get values from second floor and so on. Next, display it on my CollectionView. But my code doesn't show anything. Any help would be appreciated!!

This is what I have done so far:

```
var companies = [Employer]()
var companiesByFloor: [Int : [Employer]] = [:]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Карта"

    getEmployerData {
        self.employerCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    floorCollectionView.reloadData()

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return mapImage
}

func getEmployerData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://######/employer/")
    Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON { response in
        let data = response.data
        do {
            self.companies = try JSONDecoder().decode([Employer].self, from: data!)

            for item in self.companies {
                let arr = Employer(floor: item.floor, full_name: item.full_name, description: item.description, logo_url: item.logo_url)
                self.companiesByFloor[item.floor] = [arr]
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed()
            }
        }
        catch let e{
            print(e)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**CollectionView**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return companiesByFloor[selectedFloor]!.count
}
```

[Screenshot of Collection View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtvZc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside `do block` in method `getEmployerData` should be like below:

```
self.companies = try JSONDecoder().decode([Employer].self, from: data!)
for item in self.companies {
    if self.companiesByFloor[item.floor] == nil {
        self.companiesByFloor[item.floor] = [item]
    } else {
        self.companiesByFloor[item.floor].append(item)
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the sections properly you have to add an array `floors` which represents the sections:

```
var floors = [Int]()
```

It's pretty easy to group the array into a dictionary

```
self.companies = try JSONDecoder().decode([Employer].self, from: data!)
self.companiesByFloor = Dictionary(grouping: self.companies, by: {$0.floor})
self.floors = self.companiesByFloor.keys.sorted()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    completed()
}
```

Then get the `numberOfItemsInSection` with

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let floor = floors[section]
    return companiesByFloor[floor]!.count
}
```

You have also to implement `numberOfSections`

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return floors.count
}
```

To display a value in the collectionView use something like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)

    let floor = floors[indexPath.section]
    let companies = companiesByFloor[floor]!
    let company = companies[indexPath.item]
    cell.someLabel.text = company.full_name
    return cell       
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! And how do it in `cellForItems`?

Comment: Almost the same: `let floor = floors[indexPath.section]; let company  =  companiesByFloor[floor]![indexPath.item]`

Comment: this doesn't work(( it says on `let floor = floors[section]` that index is out of range

Comment: It's `indexPath.section`

Comment: No in `numberOfItemsInSection `

Comment: In `numberOfItemsInSection` it's `floors[section]`. In `cellForItem` it's `floors[indexPath.section]`

Comment: Right! But in `numberOfItemsInSection`, `let floor = floors[section]` says index out of range

Comment: That's rather impossible if you use exactly my suggestion. `floors` is populated with the (integer) keys of the `companiesByFloor` dictionary.

Comment: I did everything what you said. But still doesn't work. I added a screenshot, could you please check that out?

Comment: It looks correct. Please check if `floors` and `companiesByFloor` contain the correct data.

Comment: They have no values. I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Debug your code. Does the request return any data at all?

Comment: No. instead of returning something, it doesn't go into my Alamofire. It goes right into `numberOfItemsInSection` and says index out of range or `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

Comment: Please see the updated answer. You have to implement `numberOfSections`.

Comment: It works great. But I still cant show companies on the specific floors

Comment: That was my question actually) To show companies that is on specific floor

Comment: Implemented that code, but it is the same as before, any other ideas?

Comment: Of course you have to create a cell in IB with the corresponding identifier. Please read or watch a tutorial how to populate  a collection view.

Comment: I know how to do that. But the thing is, I remade it with tableview. And I know how to populate but it doesn’t work somehow. Please let me know if I do it differently on tableView!